# Can induction be used for $n \leq 0 $

Tags: induction

**Example question**

Prove that $ exp(n) = e^{n} \space \space  \forall  \space n \in \mathbb{Z}  $

First I prove by induction for $ n \geq 0 $ and then I do the same for $ n \leq 0 $

Is this allowed ?

Comment: Yes but what are your definitions of $e^n$ and $\exp(n)$? This seems very odd.

Comment: It seemed very odd to me too, but it's based on what we have proved in our lecture notes thus far. The use of "backward induction" was my main question. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you have a proposition $P(n)$ for $n<0$, consider $Q(n)=P(-n)$, for $n>0$.
If you can prove $Q$ by induction, then you have proved $P$.